# How fast is memory access to a vector compared to a normal array?

Tags: c++, arrays, audio, optimization, vector

I have a function that is called thousands times a second (it's an audio effect) and I need a buffer for writing and reading audio data. Is there a considerable difference in performance between declaring a float array as a normal array or as a vector?

Once declared, my array is not resized during the audio loop, but at the initialization phase I don't know the exact length because it's dependant on the audio sampling rate. So, for example, if I need a 2 seconds audio buffer for a sampling rate of 44100 Hz, I normally do this:

```
declaration:
  int size;  
  float *buffer;

void init (int sr)
{
  size = sr * 2;
  buffer = new float[size]();
}

~destroy()
{
  delete [] buffer;
}
```

Comment: why not you profile both approach?

Comment: *measure*, the release build

Answer (score 1):

Allocating memory dynamically has a small cost, as does the later deallocation, but you've illustrated use of `new` already so your costs are equivalent to `vector` with an adequate initial size or `reserve` call in every way.

Once allocated the operations can be expected to be as fast in any optimised build, but you should profile yourself if you've any reason to care.

It's not relevant to your `new`-ing code, but FYI there at least a potential difference due to addressing - a global or static array might have the virtual address known at compile time, and a stack based array might be at a known offset from the stack pointer, but on most architectures there's no appreciable performance difference between those and indexing relative to a runtime-determined pointer.

Comment: Note - using iterators to access the vector might be slower than using a pointer to float to access the vector. You can assign a pointer to float to the address of the first member of the vector (&vector[0]).

Comment: Iterators _should_ only be slower if the code isn't well optimised by the compiler. Use -O2 and it should translate to equivalent to pointer access.

Comment: `vector` iterators are typically implemented as pointers, so the issue is whether you're accessing further elements by indexing relative to the original pointer/iterator, or incrementing the pointer along through the data.  It's just like `for (ptr = &v[0]; ptr != &v[size]; ++ptr) ...*ptr... ` vs. `for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) ...ptr[i]...`.  Normally iterators are used in the former style, though you can random index off a `vector::iterator` ala `v.begin()[42]`.  Again, profile both approaches if you really must care.